# Can't restart mysql local server

Tags: mysql

Yesterday, my local sql server crashed, and after trying to restarting it, I had the typical error showing me it was a permission problem. But trying to fix it, I made it kinda worse. Now I still have a permission problem, but I don't really know how to fix it.

That's what I get after I do a mysql restart:

```
mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13 - Permission denied)
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 49463
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-04-26 12:48:32 1663 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-04-26 12:48:32 7fff72404300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./test/cities.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Begin with setting right permissions.

Comment: The data folder has the following permissions : drwxrwxrwx  11 _mysql           _mysql     374 26 avr 12:48 data. Aren't those the right ones?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, I ran the following command :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/mysql-5.6.22-osx10.8-x86_64/data
```

The mysql folder was missing permissions.